# Google Play App Zero Downloads after one month

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I wrote an app using Flutter and uploaded to the Google Play store one month ago in early June 2023. I got the official Google approval after submitting my app. Then, I enabled admob in my app, and I resubmitted the app again using real ad codes. Google approved the second submission as well. After one month, I still see zero downloads in the Google play store and google play console also shows no new users. In the google play store, Google shows a list of similar apps which are totally different from my app. Initially, I did not see any similar apps. Then, I started to see similar apps. Later on, similar apps were gone and then appeared again.
The apps that Google shows are not even close to my app. I don't understand what's going on. It looks like my app is going through some app classification process. My app format has a blue color buttons with white color letters and dark mode using blue color buttons with white color letters. I feel like I am not at the point where actual users could find my app in the Google play store. Most of the apps found in Google play have a rating or a certain number of downloads like 50 or 100.

Issue: I don't understand what I should improve in my app so that people will be able to find my app.

I did not receive any email from Google saying there is something wrong with my app.

Please feel free provide any help or advice.

Thank You

Comment: The play store has 3.5 million apps.  People will not just find random apps you need to promote them.  This is marketing so off-topic for SO though - https://stackoverflow.com/tour